# keras.utils plot_model return bad label format

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

I want to train a NeutralCF Model based on MovieLens Dataset.
Now this Model Code are as follow. I am a newcoder at Keras .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFcD0.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnQIh.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucH6w.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcf6F.png)

### I want to show the model layer detail information.

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
# 绘制网络结构图
plot_model(model,to_file='NeuralCF.png',show_shapes=True)
```

But I get Error info are as follow
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThWQg.png)

I think this is my Model Define method's problem .
please correct it for me.
Maybe i not define output label column , but i don't how to correct it